# How to debug missed eth2 attestations?

Tags: eth-2.0, attestations

I run a couple eth2 stakers. Lately I'm getting a slightly higher number of missed attestations, that brought my rating down from 100% to 99%. Not a critical problem, but man is it annoying not knowing what is causing this. And I know I'm not alone.

I have looked at the system and service logs before, trying to troubleshoot. I have asked in the Discord server. Each time I come away with nothing particularly useful -- I dunno, don't worry about it, you'll make it back the next attestation.

I mean, I get it, it's not a big deal... but that answer is just not satisfying. I mean, what if it *does* become a bigger problem? Then I would like to be ready to figure it out.

I'm not using any of the recommended monitoring software... maybe that would help give me some understanding of why I missed an attestation. What do you do to troubleshoot missed attestations?